# checkboxes in table get only those that are in hidden rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate, "{0:D}")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Organisation.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalExcludingGst)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExportedDateTime)
                </td>
                <td class="centered">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="@item.InvoiceId" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

So I have a way of getting the rows with checked checkboxes:

$('#exporttable').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr');

I really would like to modify this so it only get the rows with checked checkboxes that are invisible ie. the row is `display: none`.

Can someone please advise me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#exporttable').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').is( ":not(:visible)" );
```

Comment: Not so sure that works. Firstly it seems to return the result. ie. Whether or not it is visible or not. I want to get the actual tr objects that aren't visible not just test whether they are visible.

Comment: Actually this did help because I realised I actually just wanted to find invisible trs and remove them so used: $('#exporttable').find('tr:not(:visible)').remove();

Comment: I'm glad it helped, nice that you've managed to make the select smaller, it should improve performance, I don't know exactly by how much or if it matters, but it is simplified!